# Using Favorites Plugin on WPEngine for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, favorites, wpengine

I was using favorites plugin in the application but the thing is wpengine is not letting me save the favorites. Does anyone have any idea how to save them on wpengine for anonymous users?

I tried looking for it on the internet. The documentation gives a solution but by disabling TLS messages. I would prefer not to do that. Neither session nor cache storage works.